# C# polymorphism and generics type matching error

Tags: c#, generics

I've got a structure similar to this

```
enum AnimalType {dog, cat}

class Animal{}
class Dog : Animal {}
class Cat : Animal {}

class Vet<T> where T : Animal {}
class DogVet : Vet<Dog> {}
class CatVet : Vet<Cat> {}
```

Why can't I assign this?

```
...
Vet<Animal> myVet = new DogVet();
...
```

Why can't I add elements to a `Dictionary` like this?

```
...
Dictionary<AnimalType, Vet<Animal>> _vetList = new Dictionary<AnimalType, Vet<Animal>>();
_vetList.Add(AnimalType.dog, new DogVet());
...
```

How should this be done?

Comment: Btw, you're spelling AnimalType as "AnymalType" in your dictionary declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you would need covariant (or is it contravariant) type parameters. Unfortunately you can only specify these on interfaces or delegates, not on classes. One way to get what you want would be to create an interface on top of the Vet class, as follows:

```
    // Not sure what you need this enum for, but OK...
    enum AnimalType {dog, cat}

    class Animal{}
    class Dog : Animal {}
    class Cat : Animal {}

    // Create an interface with covariant parameter
    // i.e. an IVet<T> is also an IVet<Animal> for all T deriving from Animal.
    interface IVet<out T> where T : Animal {}

    // Made Vet abstract. You can still use this to provide base implementations for concrete Vets.
    abstract class Vet<T> : IVet<T> where T : Animal {}

    class DogVet : Vet<Dog> {}
    class CatVet : Vet<Cat> {}

    static void Main()
    {
            // Must use the interface here.
            IVet<Animal> vet = new DogVet();
    }
```

To be honest though, the code you posted makes me wonder if the problem is not with the design of your code rather than the syntax.

Note that though this compiles, the warning from D Stanley's answer is valid. You cannot add a method `void Treat(T patient)` to the interface now, for example.

The moment you find yourself checking run-time types, or getting compile errors because your base class defines a function taking a `T` as parameter and it won't accept the implementation with a `Dog` in the derived class, you should redesign your program. In fact, I would seriously consider that right now.

The code smell here is that you have an inheritance tree on `Animal` which  you are mimicking with another inheritance tree `Vet`. Failure to add a proper `Vet` derivative for a new `Animal` derivative will give you headaches.

Comment: Thanks. Worked seamlessly. `Covariance enables you to use a more derived type than that specified by the generic parameter` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx

Comment: Note that covariant interfaces can only _output_ the generic type (hence the `out` keyword).  If you need a method that requires an _input_ of the generic type then you can't use covariance.

Comment: What would be the right approach if I wanted to implement the function `Treat(T animal)` inside `IVet` then?

Answer (score 6):

This is a classic covariance question.  A `Vet<Dog>` is not a `Vet<Animal>`.  If you continue the analogy, a `Vet<Dog>` can *only* treat dogs.  You cannot use it as a vet that can treat *any* kind of animal.

Let's assume you have a `Treat` function:

```
public void Treat<T>(T patient) {}
```

Now if a `Vet<Dog>` were a `Vet<Animal>` then this would be possible:

```
Vet<Animal> dogVet = new Vet<Dog>();
dogVet.Treat(new Cat());  // but I can only treat dogs!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason is that generics don't support covariance. The following information is taken from Jon Skeet's book c# In Depth.

The short answer is because this would be legal but invalid if it were allowed.

```
Dictionary<AnimalType, Vet<Animal>> _vetList = new Dictionary<AnimalType, Vet<Cat>>();
_vetList.Add(AnimalType.Dog, new Vet<Dog>());
```

Since the Dictionary is being told it is using Animals but the actual objects are Cats it would fail during runtime. Again according to the book the designers would rather have compile time failures instead of runtime crashes so you'll get an error when trying to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is called covariance and this feature is supported in delegates and interfaces only.

For example:

```
// Covariance
IEnumerable<object> x = new List<string>();
```

Learn more about covariance and contravariance [in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx).